# Experiential have and let's?

Tags: word-usage

Can ***let us*** (or ***let's***) be used with ***have*** in such a way?

> Let's just have you stop being so mean to me, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

This usage is sometimes called the first person imperative, and it's marked by *let us* or *let's*, and it is so called because it includes the speaker. What you really are saying is

> Stop being so mean to me.

By including yourself, you soften the command somewhat while maintaining a wry tone. After all, taken literally you yourself are asking someone to enter an agreement with yourself not to be mean to yourself.

The complement of *let* is the bare infinitive [to] *have*, familiar in a sentence like

> **Let's have** dinner.

Comment: The embedded "us" could also refer to a larger group including others around, if there are any. I.e. the meanie is disrupting others in the group as well, and the speaker is also speaking on their behalf.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham Possibly, but then I'd expect the second sentence to read *We'd really appreciate it.*

Answer (score 1):

There's two constructions combined here.

One is the *let's `VP-inf`* impositive construction:

- *Let's go to the movies tonight.* (an offer to accompany the addressee)
- *Let's ask Fred whether he knows.* (a suggestion about what to do)

It must contain an infinitive VP, without *to*, like *go to the movies tonight*.

The other is the causative or experiential *have `VP`* constructions, like

- *I had my tires rotated.*
- *I had my tires slashed.*
- *We had him sit next to his wife.*
- *They have us signed up for monthly payments.*

The two together act as a combined impositive, intended to command, but ameliorated by using a light 'suggestion' morpheme, and an indirect causative to spread the responsibility.

- *Let's have no more of this, please.*
- *Let's have everybody stand up when the Queen enters, OK?*
- *Let's not have everybody talking at once.*

Comment: -1. You are answering a question from a learner who is probably not even a native speaker of English, so using words like "ameliorated" is not good teaching practice, pompous even. And nobody calls this kind of clause an 'impositive' construction". The widely-used and standard term is **1st person _let-_ imperative.**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was one of your students; of course you know best about how much they can understand. I'm not answering any particular person; I'm answering a question as posed. The OP did not specify any particular language background, nor any intelligence or vocabulary deficit. Indeed, they correctly used the term "experiential _have_".

Comment: @JohnLawler - What?  One of his students?  What did I miss?

Comment: @JohnArmstrong - I am a big proponent of gently guiding English learners who post here without knowing better over to the other site.